# Remove same indices from two vectors

Tags: r, vector, dataframe, indices

I have two vectors in R, e.g.

```
a <- c(2,6,4,9,8)
b <- c(8,9,4,2,1)
```

Vectors a and b are ordered in a way that I wish to conserve (I will be plotting them against each other). I want to remove certain values from vector a and remove the values at the same indices in b. e.g. if I wanted to remove values ≥ 8 from a:

```
a <- a[a<8]
```

... which gives a new vector without those values.

Is there now an easy way of removing values from the same indices in b (in this example indices 4 and 5)? Perhaps by using a data frame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
keep <- a < 8
a <- a[keep]
b <- b[keep]
```

You could also use:

```
keep <- which( a < 8 )
```

Answer (score 2):

If the vectors are logically part of the same data, use a data frame.  It is better programming practice.

```
df <- data.frame(a = a, b = b)
df <- df[df$a < 8, ]
```

Otherwise, set another vector to be the indices removed:

```
keep <- a < 8
a <- a[keep]
b <- b[keep]
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not:

```
d <- data.frame(a=a, b=b)
d <- d[d$a < 8, ]
```

Or even:

```
d <- subset(d, a < 8)
```

Answer (score 0):

First remove the indices from b then from a

```
b <- b[a<8]
a <- a[a<8]
```

a<8 returns a vector which defines which indices are smaller than 8.

Answer (score 0):

If this is purely for plotting,  you can avoid messing with `b` and the x-axis by using `NA` .

```
a[a>8]<-NA

plot(b,a) #works for point or line graphs
```